# CouchDB (Cloudant) - get unique results for a "starts with" search on multiple fields

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb, unique, cloudant

I'm trying to get unique results out of a "starts with" OR search over multiple fields using same search key.
The result should be unique sub-nodes out of the original docs.
The equivalent SQL should be something like:
`SELECT DISTINCT Name, Email FROM users WHERE Name LIKE 'key%' OR Email LIKE 'key%'` 
My view functions:

```
Map: function(doc){
        if (doc.userDetails.firstName) 
            emit([doc.userDetails.firstName.toLowerCase(), doc.userDetails],  null);
        if (doc.userDetails.lastName) 
            emit([doc.userDetails.lastName.toLowerCase(), doc.userDetails],  null);
    }

Reduce: function(key, values, rereduce) {
    return null;
}
```

The problem is that it returns duplicated results in cases where the key matches the two fields per user document.
e.g.:

JSON doc:

```
{
  "userDetails":{
    "email": "johnny@domain.com",
    "name":  "John Smith"
  },
  "privateFields":  { ... }
}
```

Query:  `myView?reduce=true&group=true&startkey=["joh"]&endkey=["joh\ufff0", {}]&inclusive_end=true`

The above returns duplicates, once for matching the email field and another for the name field.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think it will be possible to remove duplicates on the database side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using a [search index](https://cloudant.com/for-developers/search/) for this. How do you generate Name from FirstName and LastName? Assuming they are concatenated, your index would look something like:

```
function(doc) {
    if(doc.userDetails.email) {
         index("email", doc.userDetails.email);
    }
    var name = doc.userDetails.firstName + " " + doc.userDetails.lastName;
    name = name.trim();
    if(name) {
         index("name", name);
    }
}
```

Then the query would be myIndex?q=email:joh* OR name:joh*

By default, values will be tokenized on non-alphanumeric characters - you might want to play with the field-level analyzer configuration to get appropriate results.

Comment: Thanks! 
Is it possible to return a specific sub-node as the result?
I mean, get the "userDetails" object directly and not by requesting the entire doc followed by filtering it on the client/server side ?

Comment: If userDetails is small, you could choose to index it and use the {"store":true} option so that it is returned in the results. If it's large then I'd suggest returning the whole doc and filtering on the client. You could also consider saving userDetails as a distinct document.

Comment: Unfortunately values can only be strings, booleans or numbers in Cloudant, otherwise document will not be indexed.
- An expensive solution is to JSON.stringify() ...